# How to edit a YAML file using Ruby without changing the comments and the indentation

Tags: ruby, yaml

I was trying to edit one YAML file key/value but it is not preserving the indentation and the comments existed in the actual file.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you modify it as a plain text file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390330/how-do-i-update-rails-locale-yaml-file-without-loosing-comments-and-variables claims it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

Comments can't be retained when you parse a YAML file into an object, as objects, either Arrays or Hashes, in Ruby don't have a way of internally commenting themselves. Comments only exist in source code or data files that support a comment, but in either case, they're ignored by the interpreter:

```
require 'yaml'
hash = YAML.load(<<EOT)
---
#foo bar
foo: bar
EOT

hash
# => {"foo"=>"bar"}
```

Similarly, indentation in a YAML file can't be preserved, since an object has no way of knowing what the indentation in the file was.